# structure dynamic database with mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am creating a POS-like system, where there could be over hundred of products if different packages. I had another system like this before, but I knew the exact amount of products that they had, so I went for the easy way. I created a database with the customerid, and all products for the columns, and insert the price in once.

The problem I am facing right now is the following:

1. each product will have 3 different price per customer (example: price A for pick up, price B for deliver to home, price C for deliver to office)
2. each product might have different packages. 5pc/pack, 10pc/pack

I could've made a giant table like: custID, prodA, prodB, prodC,...etc
but that could only be used for a while. Since there will be new products being added into the system and also taking away some of the products from time to time.

goals:

1. able to read and update price list from database via the system,
2. insert new products/ delete products from the database at anytime

I am hoping to get some advice of how I should structure my database

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us the database and code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an unique client can have many products and a unique product can have many clients, you are in a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relation.

Such relation is built using 3 tables.

A table holding the clients informations, such as :

```
id | name | some others fields related to the client informations ONLY...
```

A table holding the products

```
id | name | priceA | Priceb | PriceC | some others fields related to the product informations ONLY...
```

A 3rd table used as relation between a client and a product, that will store the order informations

```
id | id_client | id_product | date | some others fields related to the order ONLY...
```

`id_client` and `id_product` being **foreign keys** referencing client table and product table.

If the client with id `42` orders products with ids `10`, `30`, `51`, `12` and `7`, the table order will holds the datas such way :

```
id | id_client | id_product
1  | 42        | 10
2  | 42        | 30
3  | 42        | 51
4  | 42        | 12
5  | 42        | 7
```

Some documentations for you :

[FOREIGN KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

[JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: thank you for the quick response, I might have missed one point which is each customer will have different price. 
let say  
CompanyA(ProductA) - Price A = 1, Price B = 2, Price C = 3  
CompanyB(ProductA) - Price A = 1.2 Price B = 2.3  Price C = 3.5
   and there are no formula for the price, its all up to the user and see how they want to price them. So, in your second table, I would need to have ProductA x #of Customer rows, productB x #of Customer rows, and that would be a LONG list.

Comment: That belongs to the `order` table. The table that holds the relation between a client and a product. If client C has a price P for a product X, that information should be hold where client and product are in relation

Comment: Having a long list is not a problem, DB are made to handle them, even if you have billions of rows

Comment: thanks again for the reply. so that would actually be a better way to handle this kinda case in terms of adding and deleting products as well?

Comment: Yes, if you are setting [ON DELETE CASCADE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-keys-referential-actions), when you are deleting a product, this product in the relation table will be deleted too

Comment: i was just working with the database, and some questions came up.
from your suggestion on the second table,  id|product|priceA|priceB|priceC, i am assuming the id will be the key here, and since each product will have its own id for easy access. and like I said before, each company will have its own price for each items. I am not too sure how I can organize this. lets say Candy as our first product. 
cad | candy | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 for company A, and cad | candy | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.4 for company B, even if i can put this into table2, theres still gonna have problem when i connect them in table 3

Comment: aww.. i might have messed up with something, i guess i could just create another column for productCode, and use that id for the key